# Import any 3d file at runtime in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, import, 3d, runtime

I asked a similair question earilier, but it was not generic enough, so here's another attempt.

I currently have a whole bunch of 3d .obj and .jpg files which I want to display in my WPF application. However, I want to do this at runtime, so converting them using Blend is not an option.

I don't mind having to convert to other types of 3d files, as long as this can be done at runtime (either programmaticly or by using a command line tool).

So I guess my question is: Is there any way to import a 3d file in WPF at runtime?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the FBXSDK, its native though. I ended up writing a wrapper in C++/CLI - I didn't find it to difficult (once I got used to the syntax anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a built in way. You'll most likely have to write an importer for your own specific needs. You can find some file format information here> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file

Comment: Thanks. I am currently looking into this, but I have no experience at all with programming 3D stuff. Everything I can automate I will.

Comment: You could also try looking at the code for this example project (http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/custom_model_importer). It's an .obj importer for the XNA framework, so hopefully it should give you some good pointers. Writing an importer for WPF shouldn't be too much different :)

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at the XNA project, but I'm afraid it relies a little too much on XNA, which I would rather not use. I also looked at HelixToolkit before, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: On second though, the HelixToolkit might just be perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MattDavey

I managed to get The HelixToolkit (http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/) to work and got what I wanted using the ModelImporter.Load method.